# jQuery show/hide not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having the strangest problem with jQuery's `hide()` and `show()` functions.

The site I'm working on (development build) is [here](http://intensity.emergingdesigns.com/)

On the page, you'll see a product under Featured Products called Hydrate. This product has some flavor options so what I want to do is make it so that when the user clicks the Add to Cart button it shows a layer that is by default hidden. See the two screen shots here:

[image][image]

However, when I click the Add To Cart button, the layer does not appear. The Firebug screenshot below shows what the elements look like after I've clicked the Add To Cart button.
[image]

Notice that the element style is "display: block" as per the jQuery norm, which then *should* override the CSS element style for "display: none". I've done this hundreds of times, if not more and this is the first time it hasn't worked. Now look at the Firebug screenshot below. If I click the red slash-circle next to display:none in the debug console, the layer appears exactly as it should.
[image]

Below are the snippets of what I believe are relevant code, but I can't see where the problem is.

CSS Code:

```
.carouselProduct {float:left; border:2px solid #e9e9e9; width:223px; min-height:242px; margin:18px 2px 0 2px; position:relative; overflow:hidden;}
.productOptions{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:211px;
    background: url('../images/black_background_75.png');
    z-index:99999;
    padding: 6px;
    height:170px;
    display:none;
}
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery('.add_to_cart_btn').live('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).getForm().sendRequest( 'shop:on_addToCart', {update: {'mini_cart': 'mini:cart'} });
    });
    jQuery('.choose_options').live('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#options_'+jQuery(this).attr('rel')).show();
    });
});
```

Note: I thought maybe there was some way that something was interfering so I implemented noConflict but it didn't make any difference. Also note that I'm not getting ANY JS errors in Firebug.

HTML Code:

```
<article class="carouselProduct"> 
    <!--productContent starts here-->
    <article class="productContent">
        <a href="/shop/product/intensity-hydrate"><img class='productImage' src="/uploaded/thumbnails/db_file_img_33_autox126.png" style="margin: 3px;"></a>
        <hgroup>
            <h4>Hydrate</h4>
           <h3>$25.00</h3>
            <h3 class="orange">$15.00</h3>
        </hgroup>
        <strong>Key Benefits:</strong>
        <ul>
            <li>Proper electrolyte balance</li>
            <li>Reduce muscle fatigue & cramping</li>
        </ul>
        </article>
        <!--productContent ends here--> 
        <!--productOptions layer starts here -->
        <div class="productOptions" id="options_1">
            <div class='selectbox1'>
                <label>Flavor</label>
                <select class='my-dropdown' name='product_options[4448804864d703e8b696c3fa7713aa23]'>
                    <option value='Fruit Punch'>Fruit Punch</option>
                    <option value='Orange'>Orange</option>
                </select>
            </div><br>
            <article class="product_btn">
                <a class="yellow_btn" rel="1" title="Add To Cart" href="#" onclick="return $(this).getForm().sendRequest( 'shop:on_addToCart', {update: {'mini_cart': 'mini:cart'},onSuccess: function(){ close_layer(1) } })">Add To Cart</a>
                <a class="gray_btn" title="View More" href="#" onclick="close_layer(1)">Cancel</a>
            </article>
        </div>
        <!--productOptions layer ends here -->
        <!--product_btn starts here-->
        <article class="product_btn">
            <a class="yellow_btn choose_options" title="Add To Cart" href="#" rel="1">Add To Cart</a>
            <a class="gray_btn" title="View More" href="/shop/product/intensity-hydrate">View More</a>
        </article>
    <!--product_btn ends here--> 
</article>
```

Note that there are two Add To Cart buttons. Only the last one in the code here (the one that shows up initially) has the "choose_options" class on it. Also, on the Cancel button inside the overlay, I have call to a function called close_layer that passes the id in and then runs the jQuery hide() function which also doesn't work.

I've tried everything I can think of. I've disabled other JS and CSS and still it doesn't work. I've console logged everything and added alerts. It IS running the function because it adds the element display style to the hidden div but something isn't letting it override the CSS file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you experience similar results in other browsers, ie Chrome?

Comment: Where is the **`style="display:block"`** being added? Since you mentioned that you've disabled JS and still didn't work, it could most likely be set on the server side. That needs to be removed to allow CSS to do its thing.

Comment: Anthony - yes same problem on all browsers I've tried. Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Lanthe - "display:block" is being added dynamically by jQuery upon clicking the Add to Cart button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On your page, there are more than one divs has the same ID - 'options_1'. So your code only change one of them. If you do want to show all of them, then you can do it as below:

```
jQuery('div[id=options_'+jQuery(this).attr('rel')+']').show();
```

Comment: This worked for the most part! In fact the remaining issue is probably something unrelated. But what's odd is I look at my source code and do a search and only find one instance of each product list "options_1" only occurs once. But the code you provided fixed that problem so thank you! Now the only problem is that when I click on the drop-down inside the layer, the slider gets all jacked up. I'll try to figure that one out on my own.

Comment: I didn't check your source code. But if you search your page with jQuery('div[id=options_1]'), you probably can find three DIVs: So you'd better to check why there are three.

Answer (score 3):

The issue i feel is being cause by **specificity**

`element.style` has higher specificity compared to `.productoptions` because **the property is part of the style attribute**

Even if you `apply the class` to the element  `element.style` will be **given preference.** .

The better option for you is to `Remove the style attribute from your HTML..`

Add the `display:block` inside  a class..

```
.block
{
    display : block;
}
```

---

```
<div id="options_1" style="display:block">
```

should now look like

```
<div id="options_1" class="block">
```

Now use `.addClass()`  and `.removeClass()` to specify your logic.

Comment: It's actually backwards from what you are thinking. The element style is being added dynamically by jQuery when I click the Add To Cart button. The display:none is defined in the stylesheet but when I click the button it appends the style="display:block" to the element itself. This is my confusion because the element should override the stylesheet right?

Comment: I tried doing addClass and removeClass as well and it didn't have any effect. It's like it wouldn't change the styles even though it changed the class name. It's really frustrating.

Comment: Did you remove the inline css from the html ?

Comment: There is no inline css. In the original html there's only the class and the id.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your DOM is messed up. Perhaps you have a missing tag somewhere or something?

Anyway I visited your page and when I change:

`jQuery('#options_'+jQuery(this).attr('rel')).show();`

to

`jQuery('#options_'+jQuery(this).attr('rel')).show().appendTo(jQuery(this).parent())`

everything is fine.

Comment: I tried this and while it did work to put the layer in, I still can't remove the layer. Additionally, if I look at the Firebug console the original div is still there and set to display:none even though it's visible, so by appending it, we are duplicating. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: Right the code wasn't the solution. Just pointing out that something seems to be wrong with your DOM structure. If you wanted to use this code to 'fix' the problem you could try `moveTo()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and after debugging found that I had forced 'display: inline-block !important' in one of the places which was overriding my hide(). Could you check if the !important is used anywhere in the CSS that can be related?